# I have to refer the 90% column "Total" row value for response time in Aggregate Report?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

For response time I have to refer in Aggregate Report, the 90% column "Total" row value correct?

Note: The value highlighted in below image.

Use Case:Navigating to a page.
1. Number of thread - 1
2. Number of loop - 3

[image: Aggregate Report]

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to each Request because I believe you have "Test" which is a "Transaction Controller" that has checked " Generate Parent Sampler" that adds the whole Test Transaction - Response Times for Requests and influences the Average, and maybe Consider uncheck "Generate Parent Sampler" for a better overview of the Avg Response Time.